# C++ How to use vector class to create collection

Tags: c++, vector, collections

How i can use vector class to create collection? I have to create collection of people's using vector class. I've tried these, but how i can "push_back" a variable?

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string a,b,c,d,e,f,g;
    cout <<"Name: ";
    cin >>a;
    cout <<"Surname: ";
    cin >>b;
    cout <<"Gender: ";
    cin >>c;
    cout <<"ID: ";
    cin >>d;
    cout <<"Date of birth: ";
    cin >>e;
    cout <<"Street: ";
    cin >>f;
    cout <<"School: ";
    cin >>g;
    std::vector < int > dane;
    dane.push_back( a );
    dane.push_back( b );
    dane.push_back( c );
    dane.push_back( d );
    dane.push_back( e );
    dane.push_back( f );
    dane.push_back( g );

    for( size_t i = 0; i < dane.size(); i++ )
         cout <<dane[ i ];

    cout<<"End";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't push strings into a vector of integers. Make a vector of strings instead. And then, to make a collection of people, define a struct/class to hold a person's info, and then create a vector of person objects.

Comment: Yes, i edited the code,and now is working.

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer

```
    using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string a,b,c,d,e,f,g;
    cout <<"Name: ";
    cin >>a;
    cout <<"Surname: ";
    cin >>b;
    cout <<"Gender: ";
    cin >>c;
    cout <<"ID: ";
    cin >>d;
    cout <<"Date of birth: ";
    cin >>e;
    cout <<"Street: ";
    cin >>f;
    cout <<"School: ";
    cin >>g;

    std::vector < string > dane;
    dane.push_back( a );
    dane.push_back( b );
    dane.push_back( c );
    dane.push_back( d );
    dane.push_back( e );
    dane.push_back( f );
    dane.push_back( g );

    for( size_t i = 0; i < dane.size(); i++ )
         cout <<dane[ i ]<<endl;

    cout<<"End";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Often when I see sequential, generically named variables like `string a,b,c,d,e,f,g;` I recommend an array, but in this case each of those generically-named, utterly non-descriptive identifiers represent a completely different piece of data and should be named accordingly. For example, from the usage in the code `a` clearly represents a "Name", so `a` should be `Name`. This makes the code easier for people to read and prevents bugs like the nigh-inevitable typo that swaps `b` and `d` and the hours of debugging that could result.